# Problem in displaying in Edit text values corresponding to spinner value

Tags: android, android-activity, spinner

I have a spinner in my layout and according to the values of a spinner i want to change the values of edit text. in the same layout.

For example :- i have 2 Edit Text Boxes and 1 spinner in the layout and in spinner i have 2 values (Fahrenheit and Celsius) and the edit text should display the temperature selected through spinner immediately.

Like  i have values 50 and 20 in edit boxes and Celsius in spinner..If i select Fahrenheit then values in edit boxes change to 122 and 68 immediately on the same layout.

can any tell me how can i implement this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(position==0){
                editText1.setText("50");
                editText2.setText("20");
            }else if (position==1){
                editText1.setText("122");
                editText2.setText("68");
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi...Thnx...but i want to enter values dynamically so how can i do this.

Comment: can anyone tell me how can i do this dynamically.